# Detecting spikes in PromQL by comparing short-term to long-term rates of change

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'd like to set an alert when there's a drastic change in the rate of change of certain metrics.
(like a second derivatitive).

Is this a good way of doing so?

`alert if sum(rate(some_metrics[1m])) - sum(rate(some_metrics[1h])) > threshold`